# React: How to show/hide controls on Radiobutton selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, On page load, I am displaying four radio buttons. On Radiobutton mobile, when click, it will display phone number dropdown, and hide Email textbox. On Radio button Email, when click it will display Email textbox, and hide phone number dropdown. Dropdown and textbox only shown when radio button click.
Please find my code, how this can be achieved?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form Id="custReviewForm">
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value={selected}
onChange={setSelected}/>
        mobile:
        <br />
        <select name="phoneno" id="phonenumber">
          <option>111-111-1111</option>
          <option>222-222-2222</option>
          <option>333-333-3333</option>
          <option>444-444-4444</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optEmail" />
        Email:<br />
        <input type="textbox" id="txtEmail"  value="Email"/>
        <br /><input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optcode" />
        code
        <br /><input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optAddress" />
        address
        <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `checked` prop of the radio input.
You can define an array of the possible options, and go over it and map each option to a radio option with the `value` and `checked`.

```
options.map((option) => (
    <input
        type='radio'
        name='options'
        value={option}
        checked={option === selected}
        onChange={(event) => setSelected(event.target.value)}
    />
))
```

Then show the other input by the `selected` state. For example:

```
{selected === 'email' ? <input type='email' /> : null}
```

Also, remove all `id`s from the elements.
No two elements should have the same id.